# TimeSpan.ParseExact negative time

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan, negative-number

I'm trying to parse a mix of positive and negative times with the c# `TimeSpan` using this example line:

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact("-4:-41:-4.102276", @"[\-]H\:[\-]m\:[\-]s.ffffff", enUS, out time)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't return anything useful.  It just fails and sets `time` to `0:0:00`

Help?

Comment: How `-4:-41` is different from `-4:41`? Does `-4:-41` means `-3:19`?

Comment: In what context? What problem are you actually trying to solve? There's no such thing as a negative timespan; a timespan is a timespan. What's the difference between 4 minutes and minus 4 minutes?

Comment: @AntP Well, `-4:41:4.102276` makes sense and cannot be parsed using standard method. But negative sign in each part... never have seen that.

Comment: @AntP - There is such a thing as a negative timespan - see `TimeSpan.MinValue` and `TimeSpan.Duration`.

Comment: @Ulugbek I don't get to format the timestamp.  It's produced by an external program.

Comment: @Lee The time is referenced to a future time.  I could detect the negatives, remove them, and just flag that the "Duration" was before the reference, but I figured there had to be a cleaner way.

Comment: @DStanley of course not, they're not supported in DateTime.ParseExact but they're in TimeSpan.ParseExact...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "negative" values *always* have `-` before each component, you can look for the sign and use two different format strings:

```
TimeSpan ts;
string s = "-4:-41:-4.102276";
if(s.StartsWith("-"))
    ts = -TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, @"\-h\:\-m\:\-s\.ffffff", enUS);
else
    ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, @"h\:m\:s\.ffffff", enUS);
```

Comment: Simple enough.  I'll take it.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you left extra-escaping characters in second parsing statement accidentally.